# Traveling with my spouse to the UK

Tags: visas, uk, nigerian-citizens

My husband applied for UK Visa and he said that I and our daughter are not traveling with him,but we have changed our mind and I and my 10 months daughter have decided to travel with him. With this affect my application, since my husband said we are not going together in his application.

Edited in from a comment on an answer.
We are both Nigerian applying to visit the UK for tourism.
So is it advisable for me, my spouse and daughter to apply together?
Since I and my husband owns a registered business in Nigeria, he works part-time with 2 different international company. And I also work with a shipping company both my employer pays my salary through a bank cash deposit not directly from the company account.
I have my letter of employment, leave letter and pay slip. So what are our chances of getting the visa if we apply together. Hope we have enough ties.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, your application needs to show this.
But also your husband will need to check whether he will to need to get a new visa, (because sometimes visa are given on the ties to home and if you travel with him those ties are a lot less strong.)

With the information given, I feel it is important to check that his visa is valid if you travel together.

Comment: Sorry for the little information. We are both Nigerian applying to visit the UK for tourism. So is it advisable for me, my spouse and daughter to apply together. Since I and my husband owns a registered business in Nigeria, he works part-time with 2 different international company. And I also work with a shipping company both my employer pays my salary through a bank cash deposit not directly from the company account. I have my letter of employment, leave letter and pay slip. So what are our chances of getting the visa if we apply together. Hope we have enough ties

Comment: @Chibaby Willeke is correct - if your husband had originally applied on the basis of his family travelling with him he may not have been given the visa. Even if your own application is successful, having a valid visa does not guarantee entry, UK Immigration officials have the power to refuse you all entry at the border.